# Build regular expression to recognize at least a given interval

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression given by a word and a range of words following.

For example:

```
pattern = 'word \\w+ \\w+ \\w+"
result = [text[match.start():match.end()] for match in re.finditer(pattern, text)]
```

How could you modify the regular expression so that when there is a smaller number of elements that in the interval also recognize it? For example if the word is in the end of the string I would like it to return that interval too.

Always if possible to return the greatest possible pattern.

Comment: It would help immensely if you gave an example input and what you want to match/output.

Comment: Do you mean this looks for ` \\w+` three times - how do you change it to find three or fewer? What have you tried?

Comment: I guess you need `re.findall(r'word(?:\s+\w+){0,3}', s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `'word \\w+ \\w+ \\w+"` regex matches a `word` and then 3 more "words" (space separated). You want to match 0 to 3 of these words. Use

```
re.findall(r'word(?:\s+\w+){0,3}', s)
```

Or, to allow *any*  non-word chars in between the "words", replace `\s` with `\W`:

```
re.findall(r'word(?:\W+\w+){0,3}', s)
```

**Details**:

- `word` - `word` string
- `(?:\s+\w+){0,3}` - 0 to 3 sequences (the `{0,3}` is a greedy version of the [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), it will match as many occurrences as possible) of:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UGZlzN/1).

Comment: How could it be modified so that it also recognized the punctuation simbols? The idea is to determine the piece of text where the word is determined by an interval

Comment: Use `r'word(?:\W+\w+){0,3}'`